# QueryDSL trunc date

Tags: spring, querydsl

I need to use querydsl between query for only date comparison without timestamp.

QueryDsl:

```
Date startDate=
Date endDate=
QEmp qEmp=

BooleanExpression empExp = qEmp.id.dob.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Table:

```
select dob from employee where eid=2;
10-MAR-07 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

SQL query between dob:

```
select * from employee where dob between trunc(start date) and trunc(end dat)
```

This finds records between start date and end date without timestamp. Same thin g i need to perform  in QueryDSl. Data base is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `DATE_TRUNC` is not a function defined in `JPQL` and as a result, none of the JPA implementations - such as Hibernate - support this function.

`DATE_TRUNC` can however be registered as a custom function in various JPA implementations, and then you can use a custom set of QueryDSL `Templates` to include handling for these functions.

For example, for Hibernate:

```java
public class DateTruncMetadataBuilderInitializer
        implements MetadataBuilderInitializer {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder,
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("DATE_TRUNC",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(DateType.INSTANCE,
                "DATE_TRUNC(?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

You would then need to register this class in a JAR resource file called `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer`.

After this change you can use `DATE_TRUNC` in your JPQL/HQL queries, like so:

```sql
SELECT a FROM Entity a 
    WHERE a.dateField BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('day', :start) AND DATE_TRUNC('day', :end)
```

Now you have to make this function available to QueryDSL. You do this by declaring a custom template:

```java
public class MyTemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public MyTemplates() {
        add(DateTimeOps.TRUNC_DAY, "DATE_TRUNC('day', {0})");
    }

}
```

And then use it as follows:

```java
new JPAQuery(entityManager, new MyTemplates()).from(entity)
    .select(Expressions.dateOperation(DateTimeOps.TRUNC_HOUR, dateExpression))
```

With the Spring integration in the middle however, the `Templates` are somewhat more difficult to bind to the query I think.

Alternatively, you could look into the [`blaze-persistence-querydsl`](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration) extension, which has out of the box support for date/time operations in JPQL.